# Android - can I fill the inside of an existing bitmap?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I have a Bitmap that is the outline of a green curved shape on a while background, and a Canvas derived from the Bitmap.  Is there a "fast" way to fill the inside of the diamond with a particular color in code?

I tried going through each Y-value one by one, and for each Y, find the smallest X where the color is not white, then finding the smallest X > that value where it is white (i.e. the inside left edge), then doing the same thing from the right side (to find the inside right edge), then setting the pixels between the two X-values, but for a 640 x 320 bitmap, that's 204,800 separate operations.

There is also no easy way to express the shape in terms of a Path.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Also check if [this thing](https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick) can do this.